# There is string "naveen" , want output as "eennav"

Tags: java, string

I have string in java "naveen" i want output as "eennav". Please help me out in this. The idea is that the characters are to be ordered in order of frequency, and, where frequencies are the same, alphabetically.

Thanks

I have tried to find duplicates in the string , but am not able to get the required output .

```
    String str="naveen";
    int count =0;
    char[] charr=str.toCharArray();
    for(int i=0;i<charr.length;i++) {
        //System.out.println(s[i]);
        for(int j=i+1;j<charr.length;j++) {
            if(charr[i]==(charr[j])) {
            System.out.println(charr[i]);
            }
```

Comment: Please explain the rules for how you got from one word to the other...

Comment: Is the idea to order the characters first by frequency of occurrence and then by alphabet?

Comment: @JeremyKahan ...it could also be shifted left three times? `naveen` to `aveenn` to `veenna` to `eennav`

Comment: @Idle_Mind, yes, but then the finding duplicates seems irrelevant. Anyway, we'll wait and see.

Comment: `if (str.equals("naveen")) System.out.println("eennav"); else throw new IllegalArgumentException("General rule for transformation is unknown");`

Comment: @ErwinBolwidt Perfection.

Comment: If the problem is what I think it is, see  https://medium.com/competitive-programming/leetcode-451-sort-characters-by-frequency-873f876de315 or https://medium.com/@rebeccahezhang/leetcode-451-sort-characters-by-frequency-641cd202ca34

Comment: Hah. Easy to write in Kotlin. You can do similar with the Java streams API but it will be more verbose. `fun leetCode451(s: String) =
    s.groupBy { it }.entries.sortedByDescending { it.value.size }.joinToString("") {
        it.key.toString().repeat(it.value.size)
    }`

Comment: The problem is not primarily about duplicates.  Start with the idea of building a frequency table, and iterating from highect frequency to lowest.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the question is asking us to take a string containing only lower case letters and organize them by frequency of letters (high to low) and within that by alphabetical order, we can do it as below.
The strategy is first to make a pass through the characters of the input string and count the number of occurrences of each. Then we look through the counts for letters and find the largest. Working from the largest down to 1, we run through the alphabet for characters that occur that many times, and append that many of them to the result string.
There is a little bit of work involved here to convert back and forth from 'a' to 0 and 0 to 'a' and so on to 25 and 'z'.
This approach could be extended, but since the question didn't specify, I chose to make simplifying assumptions. I also did not work on optimizing, just getting it to work.

```
public class MyClass {
public static void main(String args[]) {
    String str = "naveen"; //this string may change, but it is assumed to be all lower case letters by this implementation
    int[] counts = new int[26]; //frequency count of letters a to z
    for (int i = 0; i < 26; i++) {
        counts[i] = 0; // intially 0 of any letter
    }
    char[] charr = str.toCharArray();
    for (int i = 0; i < charr.length; i++) {
        counts[(int)(charr[i]) - (int)('a')]++; // increment corresponding spot in counts array, spot 0 for 'a' through 25 for 'z'
    }
    int maxCount = counts[0]; // now find the most occurrences of any letter
    for (int i = 1; i < counts.length; i++) {
        if (counts[i] > maxCount) {
            maxCount = counts[i];
        }
    }
    String result = ""; // string to return
    for (int j = maxCount; j > 0; j--) { // work down from most frequently occuring, within that alphabetically
        for (int i = 0; i < 26; i++) {
            if (counts[i] == j) {
                //System.out.println("there are "+j+" of the letter "+(char)((int)('a'+i)));
                for (int k = 0; k < j; k++) {
                    result = result + (char)((int)('a' + i));
                }
            };
        }
    }
    System.out.println(result);
    }
}
```

Comment: Great. Please feel free to accept the answer, if that is allowed when the question is on hold. I hope I did not give you more than you wanted. An exercise could be to extend it to handle capital letters and perhaps other characters -- to make it your own. There are definitely other possible approaches, like sorting the characters first.

Comment: Strange it is put on hold for being unclear, since multiple people did understand the question.